# MySQL UPDATE query is not working with WHERE IN condition

Tags: mysql

In *query A* below:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.val1 = 0
    AND table1.val2 = 0
    AND table1.val3 = 0
WHERE table1.foreign_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT table2.key FROM table2)
```

I expected to update `val1`, `val2` and `val3` to 0, for all entries, which I would get from *query B*:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.foreign_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT table2.key FROM table2)
```

However, in my case only about a tenth of entries query B returned, were updated in query A.

How can I update all the entries, which query B returns?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions in the `SET` clause must be separated by comma not by `AND`

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.val1 = 0,
    t1.val2 = 0,
    t1.val3 = 0
WHERE t1.foreign_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT table2.key FROM table2)
```

In addition to the missing commas, you could also benefit from using a table *alias* in your update query.  An alias frees us from having to repeat the full table name everywhere, leaving the query easier to write and read.

For more informations see the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! That was an error in my initial question, which I corrected. The problem is still there, though :-/

Comment: you were right, the `AND` was the problem. I re-edited my question to the initial one. It was a not-so-clever mistake, others can now learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.val1 = 0, table1.val2 = 0 , table1.val3 = 0
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.foreign_key = table2.key
```

May you have null value on table2.key